# Power Automate MS Flow Email Issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, flow, power-automate, microsoft-flow

I have created a flow that sends an email when a new list item is created, via the mail connector, not the outlook connector.

When the user receives an email there is a message in the bottom of the email, saying "Click here if you would like to unsubscribe from this email..", what in the world is that even for?

Especially if it is in a workflow, the user is getting the email for a reason, so obviously I do not want anyone clicking that.

How can I disable that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this thread](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Remove-quot-Unsubscribe-quot-Option-from-Flow-Email/td-p/102524),

Try adding below code at the end in body (HTML editor/Code View) of send an email action:

```
<div style="display: none;">
```

**OR** if above code is not working for you, try adding this code:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .custom-div a,
        .custom-div a:link,
        .custom-div a:active,
        .custom-div a:visited,
        .custom-div a:hover {
            text-decoration: none !important;
            color: white !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<div class="custom-div" style="display:none !important; font-size:1 !important; color:white !important;">
```

---

Also, you can vote on below ideas submitted by other users so that Microsoft can implement/provide out of the box option in action configuration:

1. [Remove unsubscribe link from mail connector](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Ideas/Remove-unsubscribe-link-from-mail-connector/idi-p/137396)
2. [Option to remove the unsubscribe from email form](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Ideas/Option-to-remove-the-unsubscribe-from-email-form/idi-p/293997)

**Update from comments**:

You have to add above HTML code in **Code View** of send an email action:

[image]

Comment: Let me know if you are not able to access the above link & I will add other answers from the thread here.

Comment: I tried this, and all it does is send the raw HTML in the email as well as show the unsubscribe form message as well

Comment: You have to add HTML/CSS code in **Code View** of send an email action. check updated answer above.

Comment: The first solution in your answer works `<div style="display: none;">`, the solution with the CSS included does not work